# xUnit test execution different dbcontext settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, startup, xunit.net

I'm currently writing xUnit test for a .net core application. This is the way I am setting up my DbContext in the Startup:

```
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now I want the xUnit tests to be executed using SQLite, which would require me to be able to detect if the application is being executed normally or if the tests are being executed in my Startup Class. To then set up the DbContext depending on that.

Is there a way to do so? I have been googling a lot, but not been able to find a good solution.

Comment: The startup class configures the application, not the application's tests. Now it is possible that you perform some common DbContext configuration in startup that you also want to have applied during testing. If so, just put that shared portion of config in a dedicated method and call it from startup

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you want to do. I am not sure I got it but I can give some tips.
 If you want to test the database in unit tests with EF you can do the following.

Create a context options builder object, using an in memory database

```
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestingDb")
                .Options;
```

Create a context using this options object

```
            var context = new YourContext(options);
```

And create a repository using the above context.

```
            _repository= new YourRepository(context);
```

Now use this new repository and you will have a proper in memory database for your tests. Using DbContextOptionsBuilder you can change the target database as you wish. I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I was looking for a way to do this in the Startup and set up the DbContext there appropriately.

Comment: In the startup I do not think you can do it. But you set it up once in your test project and reuse it.

Comment: My problem with that solution is that I am not passing the DbContext to the service, but rather passing the entity as a generic to a generic repository class, which creates the ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: Your generic repository class is using the dbcontext. There is where it needs to be passed

Comment: Thanks a lot for now. I will try this out tomorrow when I am at work again and the come back to you if this works.

Comment: Please do that and let me know